# Import data from google sheet to google forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Daily I want to update the google form (10+ forms dailys)

If there any way to send data to google form

I have google sheet with 3 column, COl1-Name, COl2-Age, COl-Location with 10+ rows of item,

Now i want to fill form for 10+ line of item one by one, So i want to send data from google sheet to google forms directly

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, you can **Import** data from Google Sheet and use it to **fill out** Google Forms. The idea here is that you have a make a little bot to **automate** your tasks. You can use any language you prefer.

**Follow** these steps:

1. Use `Google Sheet API` to import raw data.
2. Then, use the imported data to fill out the form and `POST` it to `Google Forms`

**Here** are some starter links to guide you through:

- [How to use Google Sheet API to import raw data?](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api)
- [How to dynamically prefill Google Form?](https://trevorfox.com/2015/06/dynamically-pre-fill-google-forms-with-mailchimp-merge-tags/)
- [How to automate Google Form?](https://dev.to/jamesshah/how-i-automated-the-google-form-filling-for-my-college-attendance-using-python-3ao1)

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

**PS**: Google will limit your API usage if your traffic is quite large, but since you have mentioned 10+ forms on daily basis, it should be fine.